# How to get arrowheads scaled to be a fixed fraction of the arrows' lengths?

Tags: graphics, scaling

Example:

```
pts = {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{3, 2}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 5}, {3, 2}}, {{-5, 0}, {0, 5}},
      {{3, -8}, {-5, 0}}, {{16, 5}, {3, -8}}, {{-5, 26}, {16, 5}},
      {{-39, -8}, {-5, 26}}};

Graphics[Arrow /@ pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the image above, as the arrow length gets shorter, the (fixed-size) arrowheads become increasingly dominant; the last arrow's shaft is entirely eclipsed by the arrowhead.

(It is worth nothing that this behavior is "scale-invariant": the displayed image looks exactly the same if `pts` is replaced by—for example—`0.01 pts`.)

How can I make the sizes of the arrowheads (only! <sup>1</sup>) proportional to the arrow's length<sup>2</sup>?  By this I mean that the size of the arrowheads should be a fixed fraction (e.g. 1/25) of the length of the whole arrow.  This means that the solution should be scale invariant (i.e., invariant with respect to re-scaling of all the arrow lengths).

I stress the scale invariance requirement because some proposed solutions do not satisfy it.  For example, if one defines

```
arrow[pts : {p1_, p2_}] := {Arrowheads[Norm[p2 - p1]/500], Arrow[pts]}
```

...then, with `pts` defined as above, the expression `Graphics[arrow /@ pts]` produces this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

...but the expression `Graphics[arrow /@ (0.01 pts)]`, where all the dimensions have been scaled by 0.01, produces this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>
The thicknesses/widths of the shafts should remain as they are now (i.e. *not* proportional to arrow length.)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>
It is safe to assume that I'm dealing only with arrows consisting of a single segment, like those shown above.  In this case, the notion of "arrow length" is reasonably straightforward.</sup>

Comment: `Graphics[{Arrowheads[Norm[#]/200], 
    Arrow@#} & /@ {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{3, 2}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 5}, {3, 
     2}}, {{-5, 0}, {0, 5}}, {{3, -8}, {-5, 0}}, {{16, 
     5}, {3, -8}}, {{-5, 26}, {16, 5}}, {{-39, -8}, {-5, 26}}}]`?

Comment: Similar to above. `arrow[{pt1_, pt2_}] := {Arrowheads[0.002 EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]],
    Arrow[{pt1, pt2}]};
arr = arrow[#] & /@ {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{3, 2}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 5}, {3, 
      2}}, {{-5, 0}, {0, 5}}, {{3, -8}, {-5, 0}}, {{16, 
      5}, {3, -8}}, {{-5, 26}, {16, 5}}, {{-39, -8}, {-5, 26}}};
Graphics[arr]` screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NYVeG.png)

Answer (score 5):

```
pts = {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{3, 2}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 5}, {3, 2}}, {{-5, 0}, {0, 5}}, 
      {{3, -8}, {-5, 0}}, {{16, 5}, {3, -8}}, {{-5, 26}, {16, 5}}, {{-39, -8}, {-5, 26}}};

ClearAll[aF]
aF[scale_, pts_, styles___] := Graphics[{styles, 
   Arrowheads[scale Norm[Subtract @@ ##]], Arrow @ #} & /@ pts];

aF[1/300, pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
aF[1/300, pts, Thick, Red]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  After I tried your answer (and also Nasser's), I realized that the wording of my question was ambiguous.  I have added a couple of sentences to my post to disambiguate it.  Basically, the arrowheads need to be a fixed fraction of the length of the arrow.  (If you multiply all the points in `pts` by, say, 0.01, you'll see the problem.)

Comment: @kjo, i think the update fixes the issue.

Comment: Which help tutorials should I read in order to make sense of all the @, @@, #, ##, &, /@ symbols? I consider myself fairly experienced in programming languages and this is so different to anything else I have seen.
Your whole command 
aF[scale_, pts_, styles___] := Graphics[{styles, 
   Arrowheads[scale Norm[Subtract @@ ##]], Arrow @ #} & /@ pts];
Seems very hard to follow for me

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your updated goal I believe you need to scale the arrowheads relative to the overall graphic.  If the graphic consists entirely of arrows we can use the `pts` themselves for this.  We can also use the

```
draw[pts_, scale_: 1, opts : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] :=
  Module[{size},
    size = EuclideanDistance @@ CoordinateBounds[pts];
    Graphics[{
      Arrowheads[ EuclideanDistance @@@ pts * scale/size ],
      Arrow @ pts
    }, opts]
  ]
```

Now the appearance is invariant with absolute scale of `pts`:

```
draw[pts*100, 0.1, Frame -> True]
draw[pts*.01, 0.1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

If the arrows are only one part of the graphic and it is important that the arrowheads scale with the overall size rather than only the spread of the arrows themselves then I think you will need a two pass approach, first finding the `PlotRange` of the graphic, then re-rendering it with the new arrowhead sizes.  Let me know if this is necessary for your application.

Answer (score 2):

First draw an arrow:

```
arrow = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1], Arrowheads[0.25], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-0.1, 0.1}}, ImagePadding -> None];
```

where `AbsoluteThickness` keeps the thickness of the shaft fixed (per footnote 1), and `Arrowheads[0.25]` makes the length of the arrowhead a fixed fraction of the graphic, and hence of the arrow.

Then you can `Inset` `arrow` in another graphic, using the `size` and `dirs` parameters to place and direct it:

```
Graphics[{Inset[arrow, #1, {0, 0}, Norm[#2 - #1], #2 - #1] & @@@ pts}]
```

The trick is that the size scale used by `Arrowheads` is still based on the inner `Graphics`, and so the arrowhead is rescaled along with the rest of the arrow.

P.S. I'm sure I got the idea of using `Inset` from another answer on Mathematica.se, but I can't find it right now.